# Receiving GCM messages in a nodejs app

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I'm looking for a way to receive push messages sent through GCM in my nodejs app. I've found several examples, including with XMPP ([link1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm), [link2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications)), of implementing a GCM client in nodejs, but they all demonstrate how the nodejs app is sending messages.

I want it to receive the message, as if it had a `registration_id` like any other GCM client (let's say, a mobile device). I don't mean receiving notifications using socket.io but rather GCM messages.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Where would the message be coming from? Device to your NodeJS app server?

Comment: @AL. from my server to a nodejs client (in addition to my android devices - this is already working).

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with NodeJS. But if you're using it as a client, I'm guessing it's just like any other Web Client?

Comment: The client needs to obtain a token (aka registration_id). In Web client, this is done through a service worker registration. Looking for a way to obtain it in nodejs.

Comment: Haven't really looked into it myself, but have you checked the [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) yet?